# I don't seem to understand the working of the tellg function

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char ch1;
    char ch = 'A';
    fstream fileout("data.dat",ios::out);
    fileout << ch;
    int p = fileout.tellg();
    cout << p;
}
```

It returns 1. Shouldn't it return 0? As 'A' is the zeroth byte in the file?

Comment: You should use `tellp` in this case since you opened your file with write access only. `tellg` is returning an input position indicator which makes no sense here and could possibly be undefined: *The openmode argument, required by the base class function signature, is **usually ignored**, because std::basic_filebuf maintains only one file position* - cppreference.com

Comment: @Olaf The question was migrated from cs.se.

Answer (score 0):

There is now one byte in the file. `tellg` yields the position in the file the next read/write will occur (there is just one position pointer), which would be (byte) `1`.

Note: You should use `streampos` for the result.